# How can I parse a special XML format under Python?

Tags: python, xml

The data format looks like that:

```
<doc>
<url>i am url</url>
<docno>01a064132d932277</docno>
<contenttitle>title</contenttitle>
<content>whatever the content is </content>
</doc>

...

<doc>
<url>i am another url</url>
<docno>01a064132d932277</docno>
<contenttitle>title</contenttitle>
<content>whatever the content is </content>
</doc>
```

So the whole document contains lots of small XML format content, more specifically, that's every 6 row comes an XML format. I try to use the lxml or Beautiful Soup, but they don't provide the API that read six rows each time.

Also, there are more than one .txt in the folder.

How can I solve that question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse several XML declarations in a single file by means of lxml.etree.iterparse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651219/parse-several-xml-declarations-in-a-single-file-by-means-of-lxml-etree-iterparse)

Comment: The proper way to fix this is to fix the data source to produce a file that are properly parsable. In the meanwhile, if that's not possible, you can often do what @LarsH said. If this is a really large log/dump file so that slurping the entire file won't fit into memory, I'd recommend looking at lxml's FeedParser to parse it incrementally.

Comment: larsh's answer is good enough, i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

- read the file (raw text, unparsed) into a string
- append "`<root>`" to the beginning and "`</root>`" to the end of the string
- then have BeautifulSoup parse the resulting string.

Then each of the original `<doc>` elements would be one of the many children of `<root>`.